# What does =C in ENDFIL LDA =C'EOF' 032010 in SIC means

Tags: assembly, literals, sic

I am trying to understand the concept literals in SIC machines.

I encountered a code snippet in the System Program by Leland Becks book

```
45 001A ENDFIL  LDA   =C'EOF'    032010
```

**i am confused by what does C means here**

it is explained as it specifies a 3-byte operand whose value is a character string EOF

is it because EOF is a character string we use C or is just a variable

Like wise

```
215   1062  WLOOP   TD  =X'05'   E32011
```

**What does X means in this instruction too.**

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: `C` is presumably short for "character" and `X` is probably just "hexadecimal".

Comment: As Jester says, it is probably part of a syntax that describes character literals and hexadecimal literals.  So, you might take the `C'EOF'` as a single token; the `C` is to *introduce* the whole token and tell *how to interpret the rest of it*, that is, the item in quotes that is following the `C` or `X`.

Comment: @Jester thanks a lot ...what you told makes lots of sense .

Comment: See lines 580 and 594 in the code. https://sourceforge.net/p/sicvm/code/ci/master/tree/src/asm/sicasm.c

Comment: Thanks a lot Raymond Chen...Thanks a lot